# NOT NULL constraint failed: new__PFNews_pfnews.Auther_id

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-3.0

I looked at a ton of these issues on stack overflow, but none of the solutions seemed to help me. I've tried null=True and blank=True as well as default=None and they all give errors. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks so much! The error I'm getting is this: 
1- when i am creating new post from (frontend) it gives empty post (no title, no content and no author) 
2- when i am creating from backend it works fine.
3- when i tried to remove any of null=True or blank=True or both it gives the following error :

> NOT NULL constraint failed: new__PFNews_pfnews.Auther_id

**models.py**

```
class PFNews (models.Model):
Title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Content = models.TextField()
Post_Date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
Post_Update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
Auther = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    # return '/detail/{}'.format(self.pk)
    return reverse('pfnewsdetails', args=[self.pk])
class Meta:
    ordering = ('-Post_Date',)
```

**views.py**

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = PFNews
# fields = ['title', 'content']
template_name = 'PFNews/new_post.html'
form_class = PostCreateForm

def form_valid(self, form_class):
    form_class.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form_class)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', home, name='home'),
path('about/', aboutus, name='about'),
path('newsdetail/<int:pfnews_id>/', pfnews_detail, name='pfnewsdetails'),
path('new_post/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='new_post'),
path('detail/<slug:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
path('detail/<slug:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),]
```

Comment: Now for problem of makemigrations is running well, but migrate is not running and gave the same error is solved by deleting database and re-create new database .. but it is created empty post (no title, no content, no auther)

Answer (score 1):

In views.py

form_class.instance.author=self.request.user

There is no instance author as in lower case in you models.py ... check your spellings